# Raspberry Pi camera feed is slow

Tags: linux, camera, python

I managed yesterday to hook my "LifeCam VX-800" to my Raspberry Pi. It works just fine, but it's very very slow. I tried adjusting that by decreasing the sleep duration in the code, but that didn't work.

One of the suggestions I've heard lately is to overclock by increasing the clock speed above 800MHz. Is this OK? Couldn't this damage the Pi in the long run?

This slow speed got really anoying when I ran the face detection program. It took the camera around 12-15 seconds to identify my face in each frame.

Comment: Overclocking is likely to improve the speed from "very very slow" to just "very slow". You probably need lower resolution or to explain what code you are using and quantify "slow".

Comment: You get what you pay for with a $25 general-purpose computer. Although digital cameras with slower processors can identify faces, i suspect they're often using more-custom image-processing hardware prior to the facial-recognition stage. Can you tell the camera to produce a lower-resolution image in the first place?

Comment: @RobStarling Yes I can. I will try that, I think it should work!

The reason why I'm almost sure it should be faster than that is because I saw youtube videos of people doing face detection on Raspberry Pi way faster than mine.

Comment: @DaveTweed It's alright! Thanks for explaining the matter. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overclocking the Raspberry Pi, you shorten it's duration to about 5 or more years instead of 15 or more years. Considering it only costed you about 30 pounds, those 5 years should suffice. By then you will have something else to do or have a better device to work with. The speed improvement is significant if you also change the GPU mem in the raspi-config to 128 I recommend.